# Segue VS didDeselectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, segue, ios8.1

I am using `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` to navigate through different Storyboards like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let story = ["News","Video","Twitter","Request Info","More"]

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(story[indexPath.row]) as NewsFeedTableViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

However, the `Navigation Bar` does not show up when I use this function. But, when I use segue, the `Navigation Bar` shows up.

Now the Problem is:

1. `Cells` in a `tableView` cannot segue more than 1 storyboard
2. Need Navigation Bar to Scroll in the App (which seems to need `Segue`)

Any solutions through this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `presentViewController`, that's why you are not getting the NavigationBar, it presents the view modally. Instead of that `pushViewController` like:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Probably in your storyboard the segue type will be `push`, that's why you are getting the Navigation Bar.

You might be interested in the following:

1. [presentViewController:animated:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:)
2. [ViewController Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

Comment: I cannot import a normal `ViewController` into it as it can only push `TableViewController` which is the base view controller. Swift says "Swift Dynamic Caste Failed". Any solution to this?

Comment: @user2078462: No, that's not correct, you can push any viewcontrollers (If your parentview have a UINavigationCotroller in it)

Comment: Looks like it loads `super.viewDidLoad()` of the parent class on pushing the new ViewController

Comment: @user2078462: You probably have some issues with your code. Check whether you have any segues connected in storyboard, or please add the code as comment here

Comment: I posted the code. But, I debugged and noticed that the `super.viewDidLoad()` loads before the navigation. Here is the output image. `http://postimg.org/image/ww3e7xnb1/`

Comment: @user2078462: How did you navigated back ?

Comment: Doesnot show navigation Bar. (Why?) I tried to hide it on the main page and show on the inside pages using `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)` Even if I remove the code, it doesnot work. But it is confusing that News Feed is (Index 0) is Okay. But other index, it crashes

Comment: @user2078462: if you have any sample app, can you share ? Your description and issue is getting vague

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68585/discussion-between-midhun-mp-and-user2078462).

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting the next view controller, not pushing it. (at least in case 1) So you have a modal link and no nav controller !

You can either use `.pushViewController`  or simply `performSegue` and make sure your segue type is `push`. I would go for the `performSegue` and change the `identifier` name in each switchcase.

And you can still pass data in the `prepareForSegue`

Answer (score -1):

Better to call performSegue in didSelectRow. And perform actions in perpareSegue Method .

Comment: Whats problem in doing this ?